# Two different concatenates based on the same table

Tags: mysql, concatenation, group-concat

I try to design a mysql query to get results from a Greek movie database like: Title, concatenated Directors and concatenated awarded people. So, I use:

```
SELECT 
     `MT_films`.`ID_films` AS `ID_films`,
    `ST_br_persons`.`etos_brp` AS `year_award`,  
    `T_brab_p`.`brabeio_p` AS `price`,
    `T_thesmos`.`thesmos` AS `festival`,
    `T_idiotita`.`idiotita` AS `specialty`,
    CONCAT('<a href="./index.php/search-movies/titlededj?id_films=',
            `MT_films`.`ID_films`,
            '">',
            `MT_films`.`Title1`,
            '</a>') AS `movie`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT '<a href="./index.php/search-movies/peoplefilm?person=',
        `ST_br_persons`.`ID_person`,
        '">',
        `T_people`.`person`,
        '</a>'
        SEPARATOR ', ') AS `awarded_person`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE
            WHEN
                `ST_peoplefilms`.`ID_idiotita` = 29 --> director specialty filter
            THEN
                CONCAT('<a href="./index.php/search-movies/peoplefilm?person=',
                        `ST_peoplefilms`.`ID_person`,
                        '">',
                        `T_people`.`person`,
                        '</a>')
        END
        SEPARATOR ', ') AS `Director`
FROM
    (((((((`T_people` `T_people_1`
    JOIN `ST_peoplefilms` `ST_peoplefilms_1` ON (`T_people_1`.`ID_person` = `ST_peoplefilms_1`.`ID_person`))
    JOIN `MT_films` ON (`MT_films`.`ID_films` = `ST_peoplefilms_1`.`ID_films`))
    JOIN `ST_br_persons` ON (`ST_br_persons`.`ID_person` = `T_people_1`.`ID_person`))
    JOIN `T_idiotita` ON (`T_idiotita`.`ID_idiotita` = `ST_br_persons`.`ID_Idiotita`))
    JOIN `T_thesmos` ON (`T_thesmos`.`ID_thesmos` = `ST_br_persons`.`ID_thesmos`))
    JOIN `T_brab_p` ON (`T_brab_p`.`ID_brab_p` = `ST_br_persons`.`ID_brabeio`))
    JOIN `T_people` ON (`T_people`.`ID_person` = `ST_br_persons`.`ID_person`))
WHERE
    `ST_br_persons`.`ID_thesmos` IN (12 , 270, 446, 447, 448, 449, 565, 566)
        AND `ST_br_persons`.`ID_Films` = `ST_peoplefilms_1`.`ID_films`
        AND `MT_films`.`ID_films` = 12429


GROUP BY `ST_br_persons`.`ID_brabeio` , `ST_br_persons`.`ID_Films`
ORDER BY `ST_br_persons`.`year_award`
```

Obviously all films have a director and in some of them there are award-winning persons from other qualities e.g. Screenplay award, scenography award etc etc...

Query works fine for all the awarded people, but the problem is that it returns null in the director's field.

| ID_films | year_award | price | Festival | movie | awarded_person | Director |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2677 | 2021 | Best scenery | DISFF | IF I KNEW | John | null |
| 2678 | 2023 | Best actress | AAISFF | LOVEHATERS | Eva, Georgia | null |
| 13459 | 1985 | Best scenography | FFGR | CAT POSTALE | Steve, Maria, Kostas | null |

But when the director of a film is awarded with the Best director's award then the Director field displays his name normally

| ID_films | year_award | price | Festival | movie | awarded_person | Director |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13741 | 2020 | Best directing | xxx1 | BASTARDS | Panos | Panos |
| 11213 | 2012 | Best directing | xxx2 | LISTEN | Chris, Liza | Chris, Liza |
| 1256 | 2015 | Best directing | xxx3 | CAT POSDODO | Katerina | Katerina |

Desired outcome

| ID_films | year_award | price | Festival | movie | awarded_person | Director |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2677 | 2021 | Best scenery | DISFF | IF I KNEW | John | Kostas |
| 2678 | 2023 | Best actress | AAISFF | LOVEHATERS | Eva, Georgia | Yiannis |
| 13459 | 1985 | Best scenography | FFGR | CAT POSTALE | Steve, Maria, Kostas | Alexis, Vangelis |

Comment: See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) #5 and #3 and update the question with some data example and expected result all in text format. Without knowing your data it is hard to tell what the issue might be

Comment: What is the point of `T_people` and `T_people_1`, where both are joined on `ST_br_persons.ID_person`? You should be getting an error as table `ST_peoplefilms` does not exist in the context of your GROUP_CONCAT, as it has alias `ST_peoplefilms_1`. Presumably not all films have an _"awarded person"_ and the director may not be an _"awarded person"_?

Comment: I don't get any error message. It works as it seems in the first picture

Comment: @KostasKonstantinidis Because you are joining to `ST_br_persons` (presumably that is awards), if the director does not have an award they are not in the set. It may be as simple as changing that to a left join but you have not included enough information for us to be sure. For us to be able to help you, we need DDL and sample data (as markdown tables) for each of the tables involved. I suggest all related data for two films. One that works as you expect and another that does not. Providing a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) would help.

Comment: I suspect your query is relying on `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` being disabled, which it shouldn't be, but without seeing the full query (including the `GROUP BY` clause) we cannot be sure.

Comment: I designed a new database with real records and names  at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d997be/1) On null fields should display the director's name of the "BRUTALIA, DAYS OF LABOUR" film which is Mavris Manolis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the director of a film may, or may not, be in the list of `awarded_people`, they may, or may not, be joined via `st_br_persons`. And, because there may be multiple directors and awarded_people, adding another join to get the director(s) could result in a cartesian product between the two. Instead I have retrieved the director(s) with a correlated subquery in the select list. I have also added the additional columns to the `GROUP BY` clause to make the query valid (read [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)). I have also removed `aa_st_br_person` from the select list as it did not make sense as a row can aggregate multiple awarded people. To make it valid you would either need to use an aggregate function or add it to the `GROUP BY` clause.

```sql
SELECT 
    f.ID_films,
    br_p.etos_brp AS year_award,
    b.brabeio_p AS award,
    t.thesmos AS festival,
    f.Title1 AS movie,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.ID_person, '::', p.person SEPARATOR '||') AS awarded_people,
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.ID_person, '::', p.person SEPARATOR '||')
        FROM t_people p
        JOIN st_peoplefilms pf ON p.ID_person = pf.ID_person AND pf.ID_idiotita = 29
        WHERE pf.ID_films = f.ID_films
    ) AS director
FROM st_br_persons br_p
JOIN t_people p
    ON br_p.ID_person = p.ID_person
JOIN mt_films f
    ON br_p.ID_films = f.ID_films
JOIN t_thesmos t
    ON br_p.ID_thesmos = t.ID_thesmos
JOIN t_brab_p b
    ON br_p.ID_brabeio = b.ID_brab_p

WHERE br_p.ID_thesmos IN (12 , 270, 446, 447, 448, 449, 565, 566)
  
GROUP BY
    br_p.ID_brabeio,
    br_p.etos_brp,
    br_p.ID_Films,
    br_p.ID_thesmos
ORDER BY br_p.etos_brp DESC;
```

Output:

| ID_films | year_award | award | festival | movie | awarded_people | director |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14365 | 2023 | Screenplay Award | DISFF National Competition | AEROLIN | 34980::Koukias Pantelis Alexis||43644::Mathioudakis Michalis | 34980::Koukias Pantelis Alexis |
| 14365 | 2023 | Direction Award | DISFF National Competition | AEROLIN | 34980::Koukias Pantelis Alexis | 34980::Koukias Pantelis Alexis |
| 12429 | 2021 | Scenography Award | DISFF National Competition | BRUTALIA, DAYS OF LABOUR | 18238::Kalogianni Dafni | 36433::Mavris Manolis |
| 12429 | 2021 | Costume Design Award | DISFF National Competition | BRUTALIA, DAYS OF LABOUR | 36437::Gioulakou Eva | 36433::Mavris Manolis |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u2yIYnib) to play with.